# jQuery can't decide how it would like to handle buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Simple prospect. Checking a checkbox enables a disabled button. Unchecking the box disables the button once more.

Code:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#subscribe_button').attr('disabled','disabled')
  $("[name=chkACCEPT]").click ->
    if $(this).attr("checked")=="checked"
      $('#subscribe_button').removeAttr('disabled')
    else
      $('#subscribe_button').attr('disabled','disabled')
```

I have also tried to use `prop` in lieu of `attr`. Seems like such a simple thing. Enable and disable a button. I've put alerts in there, and I know the code is firing. Just failing to do what I want it to.

Comment: can you share the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr), you need to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc) to set the disabled status

```
$('#subscribe_button').prop('disabled', true)
$("[name=chkACCEPT]").click -> 
    $('#subscribe_button').prop('disabled', !this.checked)
```

Also use the checked property of the dom element to check whether the checkbox is checked or not

Comment: @Tony Maybe OP has used the `prop` incorrectly. As of jQuery 1.6 for modifying properties `prop` method should be used. `attr` method doesn't change the properties.

Comment: The main issue in the question is that `disabled="disabled"` isn't the proper way to disable a field, it is `disabled="true"`

Answer (score 2):

In your example you are setting `disabled="disabled"` however the correct way to do it is `disabled="true"`. You can use the `this.checked` value to set the `disabled` attribute on the button element:

```
$('#subscribe_button').attr('disabled', true)
$("input[name=chkACCEPT]").click ->
    $('#subscribe_button').attr('disabled', !this.checked)
```

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syyHE/3/) here, button is enabled only when the checkbox is checked.